# How to Get Bundle ID to be Inserted Into Facebook

Tags: objective-c, bundle, xcode4.5

The bundle id

If I go to xcode project and click target I saw:
Z24R84Q3QP.com.something.something.${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}

I do not  know what the ${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier} will turn into nor do I know where it is specified.

In facebook there is a question mark. If we hover there we are told:
for security reason Facebook need to know our APP ID.

This tutorial doesn't tell anything about it.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/authenticate/

Also a friend of mine seems to be using old API where we import Facebook.h or something instead of framework.

I am stucked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find your application's bundle identifier at runtime by calling:

```
NSString* bundleID = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];
```

If you just want to look it up manually, you can find it in the target settings under "Summary". It's the first item.

Comment: Done. Changing this bundle ID will create problems due to certificates, etc. etc.